# using Codeigniter session class across multiple php files (controllers)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have two controllers, user and module. By default the user controller is loaded and the user first logs in. Once the user is authenticated (by the school), a token is issued which is used to make all the calls to the school's API. I create a session and store the token in it.

```
$this->session->set_userdata('token', $_GET['token']);
```

After login I need to display the user's registered modules (basically subjects) for which I create a object of the module class and call a function to show the modules. The module calls makes a call to the API to get the list of registered modules. For this I need the token so i try to access the token through:

```
$this->session->userdata('token');
```

But i get an error: "Message: Undefined property: Module::$session"

the user.php file has a class User in which all functions are defined (redirecting to login page and storing the token in session) while the module.php file has a claa Module which makes a call to the api to get the list of registered modules.

The session class is set to autoload!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope this one solve your problem :)

[General problems regards loading libraries, and hooks](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/81769/)

Answer (score 0):

I followed Phil Sturgeon's advice on setting up a base class to extend from. This way you don't have to keep defining the same session stuff across multiple classes.

http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2010/02/CodeIgniter-Base-Classes-Keeping-it-DRY

Comment: the token is returned to me after the user is logged in so how will i store that in MY_Controller, because that is the data i want to be global and it is not the same everytime!